# Update related property (like a trigger) in a POCO entity, is it possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, poco

I have the following POCO entity:

```
public class User 
{
    [...other properties...]

    public byte Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataStatus { get; set; }  
}
```

What I want: inside the `set` method of the property `Status`, update `DataStatus` with the current date when `Status` is changed, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code first, you can just back the property to a private field and implement your own getter and setter. if you are using DB/Model first you can override the methods in the generated classes because they are partial. I'm guessing your example, you can do the following.

```
public class User
{
    private byte _status;
    public byte Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set
        {
            _status = value;
            this.DataStatus = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
    public DateTime? DataStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When I run the code i got the following error: EntityMemberChanged or EntityComplexMemberChanged was called without first calling EntityMemberChanging or EntityComplexMemberChanging on the same change tracker with the same property name. For information about properly reporting changes, see the Entity Framework documentation.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni You will probally need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanging` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` as said in the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SetupDbContext(DbContext context)
{
    (DbContext as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.SavingChanges += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var modified = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<User>().Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Modified);
        foreach (var entry in modified)
        {
            if (entry.Property("Status").IsModified)
            {
                entry.Entity.DataStatus = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure, it's fairly straightforward. You'll have to use a backing field property instead of an auto-property:

```
public class User
{

    private byte _status;
    public byte Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set
        {
            _status = value;
            DataStatus = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
    public DateTime? DataStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When I run the code i got the following error: EntityMemberChanged or EntityComplexMemberChanged was called without first calling EntityMemberChanging or EntityComplexMemberChanging on the same change tracker with the same property name. For information about properly reporting changes, see the Entity Framework documentation.

Comment: Yes, and doesn't help. I didn't found anything that help me. I try to implement the INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged, but the error keeps the same.

Comment: you probably don't need to implement the interface, just call the members. See for reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.ientitychangetracker.entitymemberchanging(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score -1):

If you use variables with backed properties, rather than auto-properties:

```
public class User {
    private byte m_Status;
    private DateTime? m_DataStatus;

    public byte Status {
        get { return m_Status; }
        set { m_DataStatus = DateTime.Now; m_Status = value; }
    }
    public DateTime? DataStatus {
        get { return m_DataStatus; }
        set { m_DataStatus = value; }
    }
}
```